# Application event capturing/viewing

Tags: c#, logging, statistics, remote-access

We develop a number of C# applications for windows machines that we use internally and would like some way of capturing data on usage statistics of these applications within our intranet.

For example -

- How many times an app is used per day
- Who used the app
- How long they used it for
- Did it close cleanly (crash dump?)
- Allow the app to publish custom events (what task is it performing for example)

This data would be sent to some other internal remote machine that would then log it and allow us to view the statistics when requested from other machines.

Does anything like this exist?

We're probably going to end up wanting something completely custom in the end, but if we could get something up and running that at least performs some of the requirements it would help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It would be quicker for you to implement a really basic logging module for your applications (WebService or straight to a database) than it would to research and implement a third party solution. If you just want basic functionality to begin with that is..